# Xamarin forms favorite list in grid

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a favorite pages' list in my xamarin forms app. I want it looks like sample picture. [image]

My favorite page is like this :

[image]

Xaml of listview grid : https://www.paste.tc/fav-list-grid
How can I manage my xaml ?

Comment: Do you want the page to take on a two-column list, like the first image shows?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! And I save these favorite pages to sqlite. I don't write row and colum. How can I manage this row and columns ?

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your code, please add the relevant parts of the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes! Exactly! And I save these favorite pages to sqlite. I don't write
> row and colum. How can I manage this row and columns ?

For this,you can use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) to achieve this.

In XAML, a `CollectionView` can display its items in a vertical grid by setting its `ItemsLayout` property to `VerticalGrid`:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <!--  For simplicity, omit the additional code -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Alternatively, this layout can also be accomplished by setting the `ItemsLayout` property to a `GridItemsLayout` object whose Orientation property is set to `Vertical`:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
       <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="2" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

For more information, please check document: [Vertical grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid).